# Azure VM very slow running Windows Server 2016 RDS

Tags: azure, windows-server-2016

Created a small RDS farm in Azure that has 30 users on it. Size of RDS is Standard D8s v3 (8 vcpus, 32 GB memory) with premium disks and its very very slow.

This client came form another private cloud running a VM with 8vCpus and 24Gb ram and the avg use for cpu was less than 20% and the ram never hit above 16gb. The Azure VM is hitting 100% constantly for both. Only running Microsoft Office suit and web browsing. They have a hosted CRM that is web based.

Opened a ticket with Azure and they haven't been helpful at all. Ran the performance tools but they still can't say why its slow.

Anyone had issues with Azure speeds ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest running Perf Insights on your VM to give you a starting point of where to look deeper:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/how-to-use-perfInsights